# Hibernate Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class where the collection is pointing to a super class that doesn't have a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I am having this error:

```
sesion.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: entities.Elaborado.componentes[entities.Producto]
```

This is the super class:

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Producto {

    @Id
    protected Integer numero;
    protected String descripcion;

    public Integer getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
```

And the subclass is:

```
package entities;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity

@Table(name="elaborados")

public class Elaborado extends Producto {

    private float precioVenta;
    private int porcentajeGanancia;

@ManyToOne
private Unidad unidad;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="compuestoDe",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="codProductoE"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="codProductoSM")
        )
private List<Producto>componentes;

public float getPrecioVenta() {
    return precioVenta;
}
public void setPrecioVenta(float precioVenta) {
    this.precioVenta = precioVenta;
}
public int getPorcentajeGanancia() {
    return porcentajeGanancia;
}
public void setPorcentajeGanancia(int porcentajeGanancia) {
    this.porcentajeGanancia = porcentajeGanancia;
}
public Unidad getUnidad() {
    return unidad;
}
public void setUnidad(Unidad unidad) {
    this.unidad = unidad;
}
public List<Producto> getComponentes() {
    return componentes;
}
public void setComponentes(ArrayList<Producto> componentes) {
    this.componentes = componentes;
}
```

This is an exercise I have to resolve for Collage. The problem is that I have some restrictions. If I add @Entity to the super class it asks for the table Producto which I don't have and I can't create. 
I can't also change the inheritance type to SINGLE_TABLE because the teacher gave me 2 different tables for subclasses and 0 for the superclass.

I am sorry that the names of the classes and attributes are on Spanish. If you need me to translate them let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spec:

> A mapped superclass, unlike an entity, is not queryable and must not be passed as an argument to
>   EntityManager or Query operations.

But querying for `Producto` is what this code does:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="compuestoDe",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="codProductoE"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="codProductoSM")
        )
private List<Producto>componentes;
```

You'll have to change `@MappedSuperclass` to `@Entity`, and keep `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` to match the two tables you have.

`InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` will need one table per *concrete* class, so no table is required for the `abstract class Producto`.